# Uses of "Thus" and "That"

Tags: word-choice

Please take a look at the bolded sentence in this text:

> Full-stack developer with 2 years of experience combined with 7 years of studying and practising pharmacy and bio-informatics. **Thus I have a wider skill set that required for every developer.** As a developer, I have developed, designed and deployed apps, websites, and online shops, mainly using Javascript (Node) and PHP.

- Is this sentence correct:
  "Thus I have a wider skill set that required for every developer"?
- Do I need to use "Thus"?
- Do I need to use "That"?

Comment: Thus, yes. That, no. If you were to substitute that with *than*, it would be grammatical. The capitalisation of "developed" and "Deployed" seems odd though as they are regular verbs not job titles.

Comment: thank you for your answer

Comment: It's "Java**S**cript" instead of "Java**s**cript".

Answer (score 2):

`Thus` is used in a correct context. But, I'd also suggest that you add a comma after `Thus` to make it grammatically correct. Also, I'm inferring that this is a CV you're preparing, so you better avoid making any grammatical mistakes as it looks bad on your part. I'd also recommend you to write it as `than that` instead of `that` and also avoid using the word every, as it creates a bad impression about you(Narcissistic, if I may say). I agree with @bitter dreggs, you need to remove the capitalized version of those verbs, it looks out of place in a CV. Cheers!

Comment: you are right, thank you

Comment: Glad to help! :D